# Forcing Sprite Renderer to Render a Sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, render

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerLoad : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Sprite pSprite;

    private void Start()
    {
        LoadSprite(this.gameObject, pSprite);
    }

    void LoadSprite(GameObject p1, Sprite pSprite = null) // p1 = the player's gameobject
    {
        var sr = p1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        if (sr == null)// If no sprite renderer exist
        {
            sr = p1.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        }

        if (sr != null && !sr.enabled)// If sprite renderer exist but isn't active
        {
            sr.enabled = true;
        }

        if (sr.sprite == null)// If no sprite exist, adds one
        {
            p1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = pSprite; 
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, so I'm having an issue to where sometimes my player's sprite seems to be invisible. As of now, I can build the project onto  my mobile device and everything works fine. However, when the second level is completed (Right now I only have two levels I'm using for testing) the game goes to the Death scene. Then it ask's the user to continue or quit. If continue, the player is taken to the last level reached. Code works, but the sprite is now invisible. Sometimes I can pause the game, quit and return to the main menu, click play again and start over and the player appears again. Other times it makes it worse because the bullets even fail to render. I have no clue as to what could cause such a thing. SO I have this code in hopes of forcing the sprite to render whether it wants to or not.

Here's a screenshot of the mobile screen:
[image]

To the right you can see the bullets firing but the player cannot be seen. You can tell the player is moving by the offset in the bullet trajectory. (If you look close)

I'm using Unity 2019.0.1a Beta

Comment: Have you used `DontDestroyOnLoad` for anything in your game? In other words, do you have anything that is moving from one scene to the next without being re-instantiated?

Comment: What's is the order in sorting layer for bullets and the player? It should be higher than the background.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by importing the player's image again. I don't know why but sometimes the images vanish or are not render-able by Unity. At least this is true in this Alpha/Beta version I was using. (NOT using anything not officially released ever again! ) This was such a strange issue!